# Why IE 10 & 11 can't load GZiped content (js and css)?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, compression, gzip

Why IE 10 & 11 can't load GZiped content (js and css)?
When I load a page from a server that supports gzip compression, IE loads the first HTML page but fails to load additional js and css files. Showing an error in the console that says something like "invalid character" linking to the GZiped file in question.

It's wierd because IE sends the header Accept-Encoding: gzip correctly, so there is no reason to believe that it doesn't support compressed content.

I've also noticed that no other pages are serving gziped content in IE, as there is no header Content-Encoding: gzip in their responses.

We are serving our static content from AWS S3 and through CloudFront, and as S3 nor CloudFront support file compression on-the-fly, we have our files duplicated. One GZiped and one not.

Any clue of what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that IE somehow relies on the file name extension to know what kind of file it is loading, instead of using the http response Content-Type header. Our Gziped files were named like their original files, but ending with the extension .gz (e.g. file.js and file.js.gz for its Gziped version). I've renamed all those files, ending them with .gz.js or .gz.css, and it works properly now.